# Кастомные кнопки bxslider

Tags: html, css, bxslider

Не получается настроить свои кнопки для переключения слайдов в bxslider, а точнее иконки с FontAwesome. Необходимо их сделать по центру слайда с отступами от краёв 20px, не могу понять как. Пробовал как-то с position:absolute их позиционировать, но при уменьшении экрана всё равно слетали. Помогите разобраться.

js и css самого bxlider дефолтный:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    controls: true,
    pager: false,
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'
   });
  });
```

Html:

```html
<div class="banner__top">
    <ul class="bxslider">
     <li><a href="#"><img src="img/100-banner.png" alt="slider" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="img/100-banner.png" alt="slider" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="img/100-banner.png" alt="slider" /></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="img/100-banner.png" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

И простенькая разметка в sass:

```css
&__top
  margin: 
   bottom: 10px

  img
   width: 100%
   height: 300px

  ul
   margin: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использую **reset.css**. Смотреть на [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/dNZNEB)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    controls: true,
    pager: false,
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'
  });
});
```

```css
.banner__top {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 850px;
}
.banner__top ul.bxslider li img {
  width: 100%;
}
.banner__top .bx-controls-direction .fa:before {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-75%);
}
.banner__top .bx-controls-direction .bx-prev .fa:before {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.banner__top .bx-controls-direction .bx-next .fa:before {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="banner__top">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/850x300" alt="slider" /></a></li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```